# Dispalying the date of birth column as empty if the user doesn't select the date using date picker

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had a label name date of birth with a text box and date picker if the user doesn't select any date using this date picker i should display the date of birth column as empty in both data base and grid view but i am getting the default date as 1900-01-01 instead of this i need to display empty field if user doesn't give any date otherwise i should display the date given by the user.

can please anyone help me out

Comment: Why don't you store `NULL` in the database instead of the default date? I guess you've passed an empty string to the database. Don't use string concatenation but sql parameters. This issue is of less importance than the possible sql injection vulnerability.

Comment: i used store procedure for inserting in that date of birth column i took null but i am not getting empty date instead again i am getting default date only.i my previous store procedure i had taken @DOB varchar(200)=' '; and now i had taken null can you please tell me another way

Answer (score 0):

1. The column DOB in table should accept Null Values (i.e. Nullable)
2. In the stored procedure, don't specify default Value or Null otherwise
3. While you are saving in DB, pass the DBNull.Value as DOB value if not selected from calendar
4. While display check if DOB is DBNull.Value, show empty